# Excel upload with column format numeric rounding the number

Tags: excel

I am trying to upload one excel with format selected as number with scale 2(decimal values after decimal point).when i enter 233.67 and upload the excel it saving as 233.66,i am not able to find where it rounding that value.
i am using SQL database and column taken as numeric(18,2).and other one column i had taken as float in DB and that is saving correct value whatever we upload from excel. 
    but if we take format of cell or column in excel as Text then its working fine(saving same value).

Comment: This is very vague at the moment, can you show some code and tell us what database you are uploading into? Add more detail.

Comment: `numeric(18,2)` will skip after the second decimal value -> 1.234 becomes 1.23 but 1.239 will also be 1.23... you need to change the values before the upload (to show 2 digits doesn't change it to 2 digits, it just rouds it as a visual for the user)

Comment: yeah its taking 2 decimal only when saving in database but for some values its taking round of value.. like 233.67 as 233.66 and 3.34 as 3.33 and 3.20 as 3.19. i dont want round of value ,i just want to story data whatever we uploading through excel.

Comment: the problem is that excel shows 233.67 (which is in real 223.668) and later cutting the 8 it becomes 233.66...